# Error executing VBA script in Outlook Rules

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email-filter, microsoft-outlook-365

I, like many of you, get tons of emails and I desperately need to organize them to keep track of them.  So, I wrote a VBA script that moves messages from a supplier to a separate folder, using the subject text "incident xxx" as part of the folder name (xxx is a number that they use to track our correspondence), but I'm now getting the following issue when I attempt to run it:

[image: Run Rules Now dialog]

[image: Error message]

Any idea why this would be the case?  Why does it say `The script "" doesn't exist or is invalid`?  What happened to the script name that it knows as shown in the Run Rules Now dialog?

Using `Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2208 Build 16.0.15601.20540) 64-bit`

Comment: I just organize emails into relevant folders.  Works a treat.  I empty my inbox weekly.  If something is really important, I leave it in my inbox until I need it. Organization. ChatGPT not needed, Registry entries not needed or desired.

Comment: @John, "Registry entries"?

Comment: I thought you meant that by regex

Comment: ChatGPT was never sane to begin with. It is not a sensible source of concrete information and at best you are lucky to get anything useful out of it to begin with. It takes in lots of text from the internet, mashes it together and occasionally, like having an infinite number of monkeys at typewriters, it produces something that isn't well presented garbage. It is a word salad generator and should not be trusted to know what features your software package supports.

Comment: If you want to get information on whether Outlook supports regexes then Google is (until they switch to ChatGPT based results) a far more sensible place to search: https://www.google.com/search?q=Microsoft+Outlook+regex gives https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/use-regular-expressions-to-show-an-outlook-add-in

Comment: @john, regex = regular expression

Comment: You will need to create a VBA-based rule, but this won't be simple.

Comment: Why not use *unique* ID numbers, so that "Incident *nnn*" always goes to a specific folder? Do you reuse the same Incident Number for different users? Outlook and other email readers can certainly find *nnn* if it's in the subject.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, the incident number is unique to the email thread.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there are some hidden attributes that I needed to set, and the only way to get to them was to export the script, add them and reimport the script.

These are the three that I added to the top of the exported file:

```
Attribute VB_Name = "MoveIncidentsAddIn"
Attribute VB_Description = "Move incidents to corresponding folders based on subject line"
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
```

Doing that fixed the error.